# How to return null value if no record found on joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I've been tasked with writing a query to display report assignments from our company's database.  There are three tables I need to query: REPORT, which contains the top-level information of the report, PROCEDURE, which can contain multiple results per report on the individual report procedures, and TECHNICIAN, which can contain multiple technicians per procedure based on who is assigned to it.

My problem is that if there are no technicians assigned to a procedure, it's not returning anything for that procedure, whereas ideally I'd like it to return a row with the technician field being "null".

The current code I have is this:

```
SELECT
    rep.RPT_ID
    ,tech.TECH_ID
    ,proc.PROC_ID
FROM REPORT rep
LEFT JOIN TECHNICIAN tech ON tech.RPT_ID = rep.RPT_ID
LEFT JOIN PROCEDURE proc ON proc.RPT_ID = rep.RPT_ID
WHERE rep.LAB_ID in ('test_lab')
AND proc.PROC_ID = tech.PROC_ID
```

I'd like this to return something like this if no tech is assigned:

```
RPT_ID | TECH_ID | PROC_ID
 12345      456        1
 12345      NULL       2
 67890      123        1
 67890      345        1
```

But currently I'm not getting that second row.

Comment: `AND proc.PROC_ID = tech.PROC_ID` I guess the problem is in this condition

Comment: Join `PROCEDURE` before join `TECHNICIAN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query.

```
SELECT
rep.RPT_ID
,tech.TECH_ID
,proc.PROC_ID
FROM REPORT rep
LEFT JOIN TECHNICIAN tech ON tech.RPT_ID = rep.RPT_ID
LEFT JOIN PROCEDURE proc ON proc.RPT_ID = rep.RPT_ID AND proc.PROC_ID = tech.PROC_ID
WHERE rep.LAB_ID in ('test_lab');
```

Comment: wouldn't the 2nd left need to be a full outer to ensure you don't lose procedures (retain nulls)?

Comment: Thanks, this one gave me the result I needed.  I wasn't too clear on how the JOIN statements worked.

Comment: This solution will not return `REPORT` records that have an associated `PROCEDURE`, but not an associated `TECHNICIAN`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have `and proc.PROD_ID = tech.PROD_ID` in the `WHERE` clause.

You should move this into the `LEFT JOIN` of proc

`LEFT JOIN PROCEDURE proc ON proc.RPT_ID = rep.RPT_ID and proc.PROD_ID = tech.PROD_ID`

Think of it this way, if your query, the SQL joins the tables using the join criteria and then filters the results based on the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

@Janaki's answer only provides `PROCEDURE` rows if they have a matching `TECHNICIAN` row. I would assume, in this case, that either the `PROCEDURE` or the `TECHNICIAN` could be missing. I would solve this scenario like this:

```
SELECT rep.rpt_id, tp.tech_id, tp.proc_id
FROM   report rep
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT COALESCE (tech.rpt_id, proc.rpt_id) AS rpt_id,
               tech.tech_id,
               proc.proc_id
        FROM   technician tech
               FULL OUTER JOIN procedure proc 
                 ON proc.proc_id = tech.proc_id) tp
          ON tp.rpt_id = rep.rpt_id
WHERE  rep.lab_id IN ('test_lab')
```

The `full outer join` ensures that three scenarios are covered: only `PROCEDURE`; only `TECHNICIAN`; both `PROCEDURE` and `TECHNICIAN`. The `LEFT JOIN` covers the final scenario: no `TECHNICIAN` or `PROCEDURE`.

---

Given the clarification (see comments), this query can be simplified:

```
SELECT rep.rpt_id, tech.tech_id, proc.proc_id
FROM   report rep
       LEFT JOIN procedure proc ON proc.rpt_id = rep.rpt_id
       LEFT JOIN technician tech
          ON tech.rpt_id = rep.rpt_id AND proc.proc_id = tech.proc_id
WHERE  rep.lab_id IN ('test_lab');
```

It's important to join to join to `PROCEDURE` first, then join `TECHNICIAN` based on both preceding tables. This allows for the outer joins to cascade as specified by the clarification properly.

Comment: In this case, every REPORT will always have at least one PROCEDURE associated with it, but each PROCEDURE will not necessarily have an TECHNICIANS.